# How to validate Twitter data and format it in single line so that to be read by hive

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hive

I am practicing on Claudera quickstart VM.I have fetched twitter data using flume but how to validate this json data and format it in single line so that to be read by hive.The data is as follows.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=17Hy8kHqgYnM5YTJp5q5z4yJ4g7Mwlcd8

Comment: You need to have the data in the question, no external links please.

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example

Comment: I have created external hive table with right serde which got created but when i run select * from query I got error as hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException:

Comment: Data Sample(which is incomplete due to space constraint) is,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             Objavro.schemaä
{"type":"record","name":"Doc","doc":"adoc","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"string"},{"name":"user_friends_count","type":["int","null"]},{"name":"user_location"